# h5 KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'data' doesn't exist)"

Tags: h5py

I am taking a previously generated .h5 file which is 3D and taking a 2D slice. The new 2D h5 file looks complete and as expected, however I then pass this into some modeling software (GPRMax) and get the error KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'data' doesn't exist)". Previous 2D and 3D .h5 files have been fine, so im not sure whats different. Below is the code used to generate the .h5 file. Any help is appreciated.

```
hf = h5py.File(dir_path+'\ModelMC0105\ModelA3d1_15102020_170900005701.h5', 'r')

dset = hf['data']

if os.path.exists(dir_path+'\ModelMC0105\ModelA3d1_15102020_170900005701-slice.h5'):
    os.remove(dir_path+'\ModelMC0105\ModelA3d1_15102020_170900005701-slice.h5')

hf2 = h5py.File(dir_path+'\ModelMC0105\ModelA3d1_15102020_170900005701-slice.h5','w')


dz_dy_dz = (0.001,0.001,0.001)
hf2.attrs['dx_dy_dz'] = dz_dy_dz

data = hf2.create_dataset("data", (100,1,100))

for i in range(100):
    data[i]=(dset[i,50,:])

data=data.ref
print(data)

hf2.close()
hf.close()
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow your code. My understanding: You create a dataset in your second HDF5 file with shape: `(100,1,100)` and default type (float). What is the shape of the data you are reading? (shape of `dset[i,50,:]` ? Also, did you intend to redefine `data` after the `for` statement? (`data=data.ref`)

Comment: The shape of dest[i,50,:] is (100,100,100). I did not intend to redefine data, however this has been removed and gives the same error

Comment: In your `for` loop you set `data[i]=(dset[i,50,:])`. So if I understand, you get data[0]=(dset[0,50,0:100]), data[1]=(dset[1,50,0:100]). Are you sure your slice sizes match (from dset to data)?

Comment: The slice size matches the initial volume for the one plane. I can even view the slice in HDFview and the result is as expected, but I cant read it back into the modeling software, possibly due to formatting?

Comment: Obviously something is different with this data (said Capt Obvious). I suspect there is an issue with the shape of `hf['data']`  vs `hf2['data']`. It's hard to say without knowing the shape of `hf['data']`. I wrote a simple slicing example and posted as "an answer". Maybe it will help. BTW, Gig' em Aggies! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try absolute path, please. It may works.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please consider leaving a comment instead.

Comment: I have tried an absolute path and this does not solve the issue, thank you for your suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that creates a ['data'] dataset in an HDF5 file, closes, then reopens (read-only) and copies the data in slices to a second HDF5 file. Maybe you will find something to help you.

```
with h5py.File('SO_64758047.h5','w') as h5w:
    arr = np.random.random(100*480*640).reshape(100,480,640)
    ds = h5w.create_dataset('data', data=arr)   
    
with h5py.File('SO_64758047.h5','r') as h5r:
    dset = h5r['data']

    with h5py.File('SO_64758047_2.h5','w') as h5w2:
        dz_dy_dz = (0.001,0.001,0.001)
        h5w2.attrs['dx_dy_dz'] = dz_dy_dz
        data = h5w2.create_dataset('data',(100,480,640))

        for i in range(h5r['data'].shape[0]):
            print('get slice#',str(i))
            data[i] = h5r['data'][i,:,:]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and example, unfortunately this still produces the same error